# How do I set the start path of powershell?

Tags: powershell, windows-10, working-directory, xtermjs, node-pty

As far i know(let me know if you have a better solution) to start powershell in a directory you have to do something like this:

`powershell.exe -NoExit -command "& {Set-Location C:\my\path\here}"`

Now I'm trying to reproduce this with `spawn` from `node-pty` like this:

```
  const shell = isWindows ? 'powershell.exe' : 'bash';
  const args = !isNullOrEmptyOrWhiteSpaced(shellStartFolder) ?
                ["-command",  `"& {Set-Location ${shellStartFolder}}"`] : [];
  return spawn(shell, args, {
    name: 'xterm-color',
    cols: DefaultTerminalSize.cols,
    rows: DefaultTerminalSize.rows,
    cwd: isWindows ? process.env.USERPROFILE : process.env.HOME,
    env: process.env as INonUndefinedEnv
  });
```

but pseudo terminal (i'm using xterm.js) end up like this (give `shellStartFolder` is `"C:\\"`)

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Why not just pass the `shellStartFolder` value to `spawn()` as the `cwd` argument?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen lol you're right. I'll just use that.

Comment: As an aside: There's no reason to use `"& { ... }"` in order to invoke code passed to PowerShell's CLI via the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter - just use `"..."` directly. Older versions of the [CLI documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) erroneously suggested that `& { ... }` is required, but this has since been corrected.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen post it as answer so i can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the `spawn()` function already takes an argument that specifies the initial working directory: `cwd`.

```
  const shell = isWindows ? 'powershell.exe' : 'bash';
  const args = [];

  return spawn(shell, args, {
    name: 'xterm-color',
    cols: DefaultTerminalSize.cols,
    rows: DefaultTerminalSize.rows,
    cwd: isWindows ? (!isNullOrEmptyOrWhiteSpaced(shellStartFolder) ? shellStartFolder : process.env.USERPROFILE) : process.env.HOME,
    env: process.env as INonUndefinedEnv
  });
```